# Error in inserting data from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, insert, duplicates, constraints, primary-key

While I am inserting data from `Sample_User_Bak` to `Sample_User` by using the query below:

```
INSERT INTO Sample_User (Sample_UserID, Sample_Username, Sample_Password)
SELECT Sample_UserID, Sample_Username, Sample_Password 
FROM Sample_User_Bak;
```

I receive the following error message in SQL Server.

`Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Sample_User'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Sample_User'.`

Both tables have the same column names. I am just trying to insert the values in normal procedure. What is wrong with my query? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the data in both tables?.There must be records with same value in one of your primary key fields..

Comment: @Appyks, You are right. That's why I am getting that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original data are existing in `Sample_User`. That's why I cannot insert the new values from `Sample_User_Bak`.

So, I deleted the values from Sample_User first.

`DELETE * FROM Sample_User`

and then executed the above `INSERT` query.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever come into a situation where you can’t delete existing data because of other constraints you can do something like this.

```
INSERT INTO Sample_User 
(Sample_UserID, Sample_Username, Sample_Password)
SELECT Sample_UserID, Sample_Username, Sample_Password 
FROM Sample_User_Bak
WHERE Sample_User_Bak.Sample_UserID not in 
(SELECT Sample_UserID FROM Sample_User)
```